# Can I use an Xbox controller for Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2, controllers

I was just wondering, because I would rather play it on a controller.

Comment: Why one would require a working Xbox to play a pc game with a controller?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau It's not required, but some people prefer controllers.

Comment: @Rapitor. I think you misunderstood. He was asking why one would need a console to play a PC game with a controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking if you can use a wired Xbox 360 or Xbox One controller on the PC without first using it on a console, yes you can. I'm not sure why you'd think otherwise. You may need to download drivers but this is trivial and newer versions of Windows will do this automatically.

It is also possible to do this with a wireless controller but you will need a wireless receiver.

Answer (score 1):

A console is not required to use the controller for PC. You can plug in an Xbox 360 controller to your computer and it will work. Same goes for Xbox One controllers. Sony Dualshock controllers may require driver installation, though. (need confirmation on this)